# How can I get the path to a file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I frequently need to copy the file path of an object in Windows, so that I can paste it into a tool like the command line or Powershell. How can I quickly do this, without having to go to an object's properties and copying the path from there?

Comment: I've got to ask -- why the downvote?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pressing **Shift + Right Click** will bring up an additional item in the context menu for you, labeled **"Copy as path"**.

This will return the file path as a string, and it will be saved to your clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use the open source tool [Path Copy Copy](https://pathcopycopy.github.io/), as this offers the ability to copy the path in multiple formats:

- UNC for a full network path,
- or a fully custom defined format, for example escaped backslashes and path enclosed in "".

Image below shows the default Path Copy Copy context menu:

[image]

Comment: Oh this is awesome!